# Performance issues while creating Index on multiple fields in Spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, lucene, spring-data-neo4j

I have created index with multiple fields in below way,

```
Class node {

@Indexed(indexName="index")
String name;

@Indexed(indexName="index")
String location;

}
```

I have a requirement where user can search based on name or location or both of them.
What would be the performance issues in this case if i use only name or location in cypher query? As i might use only name or location while searching or both of them in cypher query.

Or
Shall i create different indexes on these fields and use WHERE clause?
Kindly let me know your opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the reply, i got from Michael Hunger from other forum.

think it is ok to put them both into one index. What amounts of data are you talking about? Lucene should usually take care of the lookups quickly enough.

you can search for

template.query("name: foo AND location: bar")
 template.query("name: foo OR location: bar")
or any of these